# What is the result of this statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working through a prepared statement and ran into an interesting bit of date manipulation code. It is critical that I am understanding it correctly since I am doing a rewrite.

I googled the code directly and found something similar on SO, but it was not an exact match of the code (I know, it never is :-) I just need verification that I am interpreting it as only returning minutes seconds for the next day?

```
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dIncr)+1,0))
```

I am putting it in a conditional statement that is comparing it to the following:

```
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = CAST(@Month as varchar(2)) + '/01/' + CAST(@Year as varchar(4))
```

*Edit* Then the variables are ran using a cursor in this conditional statement:

```
WHILE ( @dIncr <= @dEnd )
BEGIN
--Random code
END
```

*Edit 2* SQL Server v:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
Nov 20 2018 21:01:54 
Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help out there!

Comment: The first one is a `DATE` and the second one is a `VARCHAR`. How do you plan to compare them?

Comment: Replace the variables with real values and run them in a select, see what it returns.

Comment: What version of SQL Server on you on?

Comment: Aside: The code assumes that nothing interesting happens in the last second of the month. An alternative is to use `declare @dEnd as Date = DateAdd( day, 1, EoMonth( @dIncr ) );` to get the first day of the next month, then change the comparison to `where @dIncr < @dEnd` to include the entirety of the last day. Ref: [`EoMonth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dIncr)+1,0))
```

This gets the last day of the current month for the date `@dIncr`

Breaking this down:

```
DATEDIFF(m,0,@dIncr)+1
```

Says: Return the number of months + 1 for the date in the variable `@dIncr` since the sql date epoch of January 1 1900 (This is the `0` in the function)

```
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dIncr)+1,0)
```

Says: Return the date represented by adding that previously calculated number of months to the sql date epoch January 1 1900

```
DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@dIncr)+1,0))
```

Says: Subtract a second from that date.

Answer (score 1):

That's a "trick" to determine the last day of the month that your first date falls in.  If you run it like this it becomes easier to follow:

```
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '20170101';
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = DATEADD(SECOND, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @dIncr) + 1, 0));
SELECT @dEnd;
```

Which will give an answer of 31-01-2017.